# Windows 10, constant disk access(+)

Tags: windows-10

For even a just installed OS I am observing the following activity that prevents the secondary HDDs to go into sleep. Can someone confirm that it is normal? What is the possible reason for that?

ProcMon;

[image: ProcMon screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that Windows is accessing the disk.

My guess is that Windows is indexing the  disk, and this will take
some time. Just wait patiently for it to finish.
Leave your computer on, to help it finish faster.

Comment: Those drives are not included in the indexing list by default .